# How do you graph using Rows instead of Series?

Tags: vba, excel, graph, charts

I'm doing a VBA Excel code which graphs certain data, yet the limit of 225 data series keeps showing up even when it was specified to plot by rows, how can this be fixed?

```
Y=1197
Set DChart = Charts.Add
   With DChart
      .ChartType = xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers
      .SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:" & "B" & Y), PlotBy:=xlRows
   End With
```

Comment: I'm afraid you can't. It is a limit. But what do you mean with "using Rows instead of Series"? With your code you have a `Series` each row. Using `PlotBy:=xlColumns` you would have only one `Series` with column `A` as x-values and column `B` as y-Values.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are plotting this `PlotBy:=xlRows` and you should rather use `PlotBy:=xlColumns`.

Because with **`PlotBy:=xlRows`, you'd have 1196 Series** and even if it worked, it wouldn't be relevant for anything. With **`PlotBy:=xlColumns`, you'll have only 1 Serie** with all your data point.

I generally take this as a base, I tuned the first block for you the rest is there for information :

```
Sub Graph()

Dim Gr As Chart, _
    Sr As Series, _
    Src_Name As String

Src_Name = "Sheet1"
Set Gr = ActiveWorkbook.Charts.Add

With Gr
    '----Source Data Definition
    .SetSourceData Source:=Range(Sheets(Src_Name).Cells(2, 1), Sheets(Src_Name).Cells(1197, 2)), PlotBy:=xlColumns
    '----Graph Type
    .ChartType = xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers
    '----Location/Placement
    .Location Where:=xlLocationAsNewSheet, Name:="NewSheetName"
    '----Title
    .HasTitle = True
    .ChartTitle.Characters.Text = "Chart Title"


    '----Data Series 1
    Set Sr = .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    With Sr
        .Values = Range(Sheets(Src_Name).Cells(2, 2), Sheets(Src_Name).Cells(20, 5))
        .XValues = Range(Sheets(Src_Name).Cells(2, 1), Sheets(Src_Name).Cells(20, 1))
        .AxisGroup = 1
        .Name = "MTTF"
    End With
    '----Data Series 2
    Set Sr = .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    With Sr
        .Values = Range(Sheets(Src_Name).Cells(2, 2), Sheets(Src_Name).Cells(20, 5))
        .XValues = Range(Sheets(Src_Name).Cells(2, 1), Sheets(Src_Name).Cells(20, 1))
        .Name = "MTTR"
        '----Placing a Serie on Second axis
        .AxisGroup = 2
    End With
    '----Series' formats
    '.SeriesCollection(i).Delete
    '----For a line type chart
    '.SeriesCollection(i).Format.Line.Weight = 1
    '.SeriesCollection(i).Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(int1 as integer, int1 as integer, int3 as integer)
    '----For an area type chart
    '.SeriesCollection(i).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(int1 as integer, int1 as integer, int3 as integer)

    '----Axis parameters
    .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
    .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Age"
    .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
    .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Hours"
    .PlotArea.Interior.ColorIndex = 2
    .Axes(xlValue).MajorGridlines.Border.LineStyle = xlDot
    .ChartArea.Font.Size = 14
    .Deselect

    '----Legend positioning
    With .Legend
        .Left = 350
        .Top = 75
    End With
    '----Drawing area positiong
    With .PlotArea
        .Width = 550
        .Height = 350
    End With
End With

'----Free memory
Set Gr = Nothing
Set Sr = Nothing

End Sub
```